# Como pasar datos de una clase a otra clase dentro del mismo archivo en angular

Tags: angular9

//en un componente de mi aplicacion de angular estoy usando un `Bootom sheet`, la clase de ese componente y la clase del componente original están dentro del mismo `component.ts`, lo que quiero es que al abrir el `Booton sheet` quiero ingresar datos del componente original pero no se como pasar esos datos, dejo mi componente

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-publicaciones',
   templateUrl: './publicaciones.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./publicaciones.component.css']
})
 export class PublicacionesComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(
     private httpPublic: PublicacionesService,
     private auth: PrivateService,
     private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
   ) { }

   public URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000'
   public id: string;

   ngOnInit(): void {
     console.log(this.nombre)
     this.httpPublic.verPublic()
       .subscribe((res: any) => {
         this.publicaciones = res
         console.log(this.publicaciones)
       })
     this.auth.datosUser()
       .subscribe((res: any)=>{
         this.id = res._id
       })
   }

   publicaciones: any[]

   openBottomSheet(index): void {
     this._bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExample)
   }

 }


 @Component({
   selector: 'aviso',
   templateUrl: 'actividad-publicacion.html'
 })
 export class BottomSheetOverviewExample {
   constructor(
     private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetOverviewExample>
     ) {}


   openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
     this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss()
     event.preventDefault()
   }

 }
```

//Me pueden indicar una solucion para que cuando se ejecute el metodo `openBottomSheet(index)` pueda pasar datos de ese componente al que esta abajo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

1. En el componente padre, envia la data a travez de la propiedad `data`

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-publicaciones',
   templateUrl: './publicaciones.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./publicaciones.component.css']
})
 export class PublicacionesComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(
     private httpPublic: PublicacionesService,
     private auth: PrivateService,
     private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
   ) { }

   public URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000'
   public id: string;

   ngOnInit(): void {
     console.log(this.nombre)
     this.httpPublic.verPublic()
       .subscribe((res: any) => {
         this.publicaciones = res
         console.log(this.publicaciones)
       })
     this.auth.datosUser()
       .subscribe((res: any)=>{
         this.id = res._id
       })
   }

   publicaciones: any[]

   openBottomSheet(index): void {
     this._bottomSheet.open(
        BottomSheetOverviewExample,
        // Enviando data al Bottom-Sheet.
        { data: { nombres: ['Frodo', 'Bilbo'] } }
     );
   }

 }
```

2. En el componente Bottom-Sheet:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

 @Component({
   selector: 'aviso',
   templateUrl: 'actividad-publicacion.html'
 })
 export class BottomSheetOverviewExample {
   constructor(
     // Recibiendo data desde componente padre...
     @Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any
     private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetOverviewExample>
     ) {}


   openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
     this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss()
     event.preventDefault()
   }

 }
```

Mas información y detalles los puedes encontrar en la documentación: https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview